# Sorting a plist array for TableView in Swift

Tags: swift, sorting, nsarray, tableview, plist

I am having some trouble doing in Swift what was in Objective C quite easy. That is, to sort a plist into alphabetical order on the field "title" before populating the cells.

The whole 'sort' process looks as though it should be easier in Swift, but I'm just not getting it. I've trawled SO but without getting a solution. Any help much appreciated. (Am not putting all the code here as it would be superfluous).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        let sourcePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyAnnotationsUSA.plist")

        if let myMuseums = NSArray(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String){
                for item in myMuseums {
                    titleData.append(item.objectForKey("title") as! String)
                    subTitleData.append(item.objectForKey("subtitle") as! String)
                    stateData.append(item.objectForKey("state") as! String)

etc.etc......
```

Comment: Thanks PravinS. You did the code edit before I got back to it :-)

Comment: How do you want to sort? I mean based on which parameter you wanna sort?

Comment: I want to sort the array on the keycode "title". This is what I did in Objective C and I want to do the same in Swift:                                          //sort alphabetically by title
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];_sortedTitle = [_content sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
    }
    return _sortedTitle;
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're disassociating the data too early. How about this:

```
var data: [(String, String, String)] = []
if let myMuseums = NSArray(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String){
    for item in myMuseums {
        data.append((item.objectForKey("title") as! String, item.objectForKey("subtitle") as! String, item.objectForKey("state") as! String))
    }
}
data.sortInPlace({$0.0 < $1.0})
titleData = data.map({$0.0})
subTitle = data.map({$0.1})
stateData = data.map({$0.2})
```

... and watch those forced unwraps...!

Comment: Thank you but not what I was looking for. In Obj C I just sorted the entire array on one key, that of title.

Comment: `-(NSArray *)content
{
    if (!_content) {
  content = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyAnnotationsUSA" ofType:@"plist"]];
        
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
        _sortedTitle = [_content sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
    }
    return _sortedTitle;
}`

Comment: What's wrong with  
`if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyAnnotationsUSA", ofType: "plist"), content = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
        let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        let sortedTitle = content.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
}`

Comment: Many thanks Grimxn. Just been out for lunch and so good to come back and solve a problem thanks you your help. I am downloading the pList so not accessing it from the mainBundle. So I did a bit of fiddling around and got it working. Again, thank you. I'll post the code for others

Answer (score 0):

Had some great help here on SO and resolved the issue. I am downloading the pList from a server and so it is not saved in the mainBundle. This was the solution (excuse the white space which I have used to separate the different elements):

```
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let sourcePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("MyAnnotationsUSA.plist")

    if let content = NSArray(contentsOfFile: sourcePath as String){


    let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
    let myMuseum = content.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])

        for item in myMuseum{
                titleData.append(item.objectForKey("title") as! String)
                subTitleData.append(item.objectForKey("subtitle") as! String)
```